# Add progress to file uploading using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How can I get progress of file uploading?

```
// import Alamofire
  func uploadWithAlamofire() {
    let image = UIImage(named: "myImage")!

    // define parameters
    let parameters = [
      "hometown": "yalikavak",
      "living": "istanbul"
    ]

    // Begin upload
    Alamofire.upload(.POST, "upload_url",
      // define your headers here
      headers: ["Authorization": "auth_token"],
      multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        // import image to request
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
          multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "myImage.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }

        // import parameters
        for (key, value) in parameters {
          multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        }
      }, // you can customise Threshold if you wish. This is the alamofire's default value
      encodingMemoryThreshold: Manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
      encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
          upload.responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
          }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
          print(encodingError)
        }
    })
  }
```

I know something like I have to add progress block but don't know where can I add that progress block.

```
.progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
        println("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
    }
```

I want to add above block and how can I calculate estimated time for video uploading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
Alamofire.upload(
    .POST,
    URLString: "http://httpbin.org/post",
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: unicornImageURL, name: "unicorn")
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: rainbowImageURL, name: "rainbow")
    },
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in

            let progress: Float = Float(totalBytesRead)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead) // you can give this progress to progressbar progress

               let value = Int(progress * 100) // this is the percentage of the video uploading


                print(totalBytesRead)

            }
            upload.responseJSON { request, response, result in
                debugPrint(result)
            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: How can I show upload progress inside uitableviewCell ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use other version of **upload** method in Alamofire and have the progress.

```
let request = Alamofire.upload(.POST, "upload_url", headers: ["Authorization": "auth_token"], data: imageData!)


request.responseJSON { (response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) in
    switch response.result {
        case let .Success(result):
            // do something with data
            print(result)
        case let .Failure(error):
            // Error occurred
            print(error)
    }
}

request.progress { (bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalExpectedBytesToWritten: Int64) in

    let uploadProgress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalExpectedBytesToWritten)
    // Keep track of progress
}
```

Comment: could you please update the code to Alamofire 5 ? request.progress is no longer available :(