# Swift 3 Alamofire Request Progress

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have this kind of code

```
let req = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    req.downloadProgress { (progress) in
        print("progess!", Float(req.progress.fractionCompleted))
    }

    req.responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print(response.result.value!)
        }
        else {
            print(response.result.error!)
        }
    }
```

The result doesn't give me a progress. it just returns `1.0`, that's it, but I need the progress of this request.

Please somebody help me.

Comment: you want to show uploading progress ?

Comment: @MaheshDangar yess

Comment: then where is your attached multipartFormData  ?

Comment: have a look at this post it will help to achive what you want :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888559/add-progress-to-file-uploading-using-alamofire?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You are making a mistake when use `req.progress.fractionCompleted`. use `progress.fractionCompleted` instead.

```
let req = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    req.downloadProgress { (progress) in
        print("progess!", Float(progress.fractionCompleted))
    }

    req.responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print(response.result.value!)
        }
        else {
            print(response.result.error!)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add progress in main queue

```
request?.downloadProgress(queue: .main,closure: {progress in
        self.downloadProcess.text = "Download \((progress.fractionCompleted*100))% completed"
        print(self.downloadProcess.text)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

    })
```